# Is there a reason why OS X Mavericks Server is running Postgresql?

Tags: macos, server.app, postgresql

I recently installed OS X Mavericks Server on my computer to use for Xcode continuous integration. I now see that the postgresql database is running via the Activity Monitor, and some investigation shows that it was started by Server.app, which is running Python, which started Postgres. I know that postgres is small and doesn't take up much resources, but I am just curious: Is there a reason why Server.app is running the database? I don't see a postgres service to turn on or off (which to be honest would be a great service to run via the server app).

Answer (score 2):

From the [OS X Server Advanced Administration](https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/3.0/#apdFEA2DEAA-4ED8-4020-94A9-40EA420C18C6) manual, under the section on Postgres backups:

> The Server app on OS X Mavericks supports three separate database clusters:
>
> - Calendar and Contacts
> - Profile Manager
> - Wiki and Xcode server

Comment: I run none of those but it still runs